# How do I use JQuery to allow more than one possible view per tab?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, performance, tabs

### Problem:

I have a vertical tab system from foundation, and in the first tab's corresponding container, there are two main components: a list of objects and a button that, when clicked, should display a form to create another one of these objects in the same container without having to reload the page.  Once the form is submitted, the original content with the list of objects (now including the newly added object), and that button to create a new object.

I am using Foundation 3's vertical tabs and have something like this:

```
<div class="four columns">
  <dl class="vertical tabs">
    <dd id="firstTab" class="active"><a href="#1">1</a></dd>
    <dd id="secondTab><a href="#2">2</a></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div class="twelve columns">
  <ul class="tabs-content contained">
    <li class="active" id="1Tab">
      <a id="formButton" class="large success button radius">Show Form</a>
    </li>
    <li id="2Tab">2</li>
    <li id="formTab">form goes here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I was previously trying to get this to work with AngularJS.  However, it has been suggested to me that if I stick with just pure DOM manipulation that AngularJS isn't really required, and now I have a better understanding of why that is too.  Would what I'm looking for here be better implemented with JQuery or even a lighter version like Zepto.js, considering that Zepto is the javascript framework being used by Foundation?  Can someone help me get pointed in the right direction?

### Update:

This is the jQuery that I ended up using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("firstTab").removeClass("active");
    $("1Tab").removeClass("active");
    $("formTab").addClass("active");
})
```

The problem with this solution so far is that I can only bring up the form one time.  This allows me to change my mind about filling out the form and click another tab.  But if I try to click the form button again after that, the form doesn't come up anymore.  The developer window indicates that the classes of "active" are still being added and removed.  But I think the issue is that the object that this form is used for is a Class.new() object that I create with an embedded ruby statement just before the form in the DOM.  Is there a way to make this Class.new() instantiation happen with each button click rather than only when the whole page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but you can show/hide elements with ng-show attribute. Here is an example on how to use it:

```
<div class="four columns">
  <dl class="vertical tabs">
    <dd class="active"><a href="#1">1</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#2">2</a></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div class="twelve columns">
  <ul class="tabs-content contained">
    <li class="active" id="1Tab">
      <a id="formButton" class="large success button radius" ng-click="showForm()">Show Form</a>
    </li>
    <li id="2Tab">2</li>
    <li id="formTab"><form ng-show="isVisible"><input type="text" value="Hi! I'm visible!"/></form></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now you manage your isVisible property in the controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("FormCtrl", function ($scope) {
    //set it to false initially
    $scope.isVisible = false;
    $scope.showForm = function () {
        //change to visible after click
        $scope.isVisible = true;
    }
});
```

If you want to add a class depending on a property, you can use ng-class:

```
<div class="four columns">
  <dl class="vertical tabs">
    <dd class="active"><a href="#1">1</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#2">2</a></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div class="twelve columns">
  <ul class="tabs-content contained">
    <li ng-class="{selected: tag.isSelected}" id="1Tab">
      <a id="formButton" class="large success button radius" ng-click="showForm()">Show Form</a>
    </li>
    <li id="2Tab">2</li>
    <li id="formTab"><form ><input type="text" value="Hi! I'm visible!"/></form></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I'm not able to try this suggestion yet, but after reading this, I just had a quick question: Do I not need to worry about the class="active" parts on the dd and li elements?

Comment: You can use ng-class, I added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks!  So I finally got to test out your suggestion and I think I might be missing something.  When I go to the page in question, the first tab is selected, but it's content is hidden.  If I click on another tab and then back to the first one, the correct content is displayed for the first tab.  When I click on the button that now appears (as it should), nothing happens.  My best guess is that the tabs from foundation have javascript that changes the class attribute of each tab element.  Would you be able to suggest further steps to solve the problem?  I'm still a little bit confused.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback @EugenioCuevas!  I have made changes to my question now that I have decided to refrain from relying on angularjs for this type of functionality (purely DOM manipulation).